# Fabric on iOS - Energy Consumptions

Tags: ios, battery, google-fabric

I'm troubleshooting energy consumption on an iOS app and have found that Fabric appears to be keeping the energy consumption in the high/very high range, even when the app is in the background. This is running in Debug mode. Is anyone else seeing this? Is there anything I can do? This is the debug info I get from Fabric:

```
2017-07-11 11:10:28.049449-0700 MyApp[****:*******] [Crashlytics:Answers] Answers enabled with settings: {
"flush_interval_secs" = 10;
"flush_on_background" = 1;
"forward_to_google_analytics" = 0;
"include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events" = 0;
"max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
"max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
"max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
"sampling_rate" = 1;
"track_custom_events" = 1;
"track_predefined_events" = 1;
"track_view_controllers" = 0;
url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";
}
2017-07-11 11:10:28.051540-0700 MyApp[****:*******] [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
"com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.2.0";
"com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.7.0";
"io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.6.7";
}
```